# Contact Form In HTML File with Php Not Working

Tags: php, html, forms

Below is My HTML Page for Contact Form

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
  <div class="field name-box">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Who Are You?" />
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
    <span class="ss-icon">check</span>
  </div>
  <div class="field name-box">
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="What is your Last Name?" />
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
    <span class="ss-icon">check</span>
  </div>
  <div class="field email-box">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="example@email.com" />
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <span class="ss-icon">check</span>
  </div>
  <div class="field phonenum-box">
    <input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone Number" />
    <label for="telephone">Phone</label>
    <span class="ss-icon">check</span>
  </div>
  <div class="field msg-box">
    <textarea name="comment" rows="4" placeholder="Your message goes here..." /></textarea>
    <label for="comment">Message</label>
    <span class="ss-icon">check</span>
  </div>
  <div class="send wow shake" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay=".3s">
    <input type="submit" value="Send email">
  </div>
</form>
```

**This is My Php Section**

Before Contact form in HTML

```
    <?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
```

**After Contact Form**

```
              <?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $first_name=$_REQUEST['first_name'];
    $last_name=$_REQUEST['last_name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $telephone=$_REQUEST['telephone'];
    $comment=$_REQUEST['comment'];
    if (($first_name=="")||($last_name=="")||($email=="")||($telephone=="")||($comment==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
        }
    else{       
        $from="From: $first_name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Message sent using your contact form";
        // mail("divyansh025@gmail.com", $subject, $comment, $from);
        echo "Thank You For Contacting Us.";
        }
    }  
?>
```

Note I am Using Both Code in Same index.php
I am Getting Thank You message but not Receiving. Other Site on Same server are working.

Comment: Are you not getting mail? if yes then one thing remember mail function is not work in localhost.

Comment: @bhavinthummar I am using on My Hosting of Hostgator

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 $action=$_REQUEST['action'];
 if ($action=="")
```

to

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
```

Other problems that I have seen in your form:

1. $_REQUEST method is prone to security vulnerability use $_POST instead.
2. You have not done any sanitization check on input received from user. Please do it.
3. As I see from your form you want to send mail. then why you have commented out the mail sending part?

So for the mail function to work add/change in php.ini set

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.secureserver.net //ADDRESS OF YOUR SMTP SERVER
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: After Doing this. I am Getting this Message instead of Showing Form All fields are required, please fill the form again.

Comment: What change you have made? Have you changed the $_REQUEST to $_POST

Comment: And put the form inside the else statement. And logic inside if statement.